# Haskell Couldn't match type ‘String -> [Int]’ with ‘[a0]’

Tags: haskell, types

I want to create a program counting occurrence of all elements in a list and return max sequence. I have a problem with my input part.

The input consists of several test cases. Each test case starts with a line containing two integers n and q (1 ≤ n, q ≤ 100000). The next line contains n integers a1 , ... , an (-100000 ≤ ai ≤ 100000

I want readNQ to get n and q as [int] then pass to readArray that will read n element and assign to [int] as following

```
module Main where

import Text.Printf
import Data.List

main :: IO()
main = interact (showResults . maxSeqLength . readArray. readNQ)

readNQ :: String -> [Int]
readNQ =  take 2 . (map read) . words

readArray :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
readArray (n:xs) = take n . (map read) . words


showResults ::  Int -> String
showResults x = printf "\n %d" x

maxSeqLength :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
maxSeqLength [] = 0
maxSeqLength xs = (maximum . map length . group) xs
```

However, there is an error.

frequent.hs:13:47: error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘String -> [Int]’ with ‘[a0]’
  Expected type: String -> [a0]
    Actual type: String -> String -> [Int]
• Probable cause: ‘(.)’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘readArray . readNQ’
  In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
    ‘maxSeqLength . readArray . readNQ’
  In the first argument of ‘interact’, namely
    ‘(showResults . maxSeqLength . readArray . readNQ)’
```

what is wrong with the type of readNQ and readArray?

Answer (score 0):

```
readArray :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
```

This takes a `[Int]` and returns a function `String -> [Int]`

```
maxSeqLength :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
```

This accepts a list `[a]` and returns an `Int`.

Since a function `String -> [Int]` is not a list `[a]`, you can't compose them using `(.)`.

---

Error aside, also note that

```
readNQ =  take 2 . (map read) . words
```

reads the first two ints from the input, and discard the rest. It's gone. The next function in your function chain `(... . fun . readNQ)` can not access what was thrown away from the first function.

You need to rework your `readNQ` so that it returns a pair `([n1,n2], restOfTheInput)` if you want the next function to use it.

Probably, the code will become too complex to be expressed in pointfree style, but that's OK. Further, `interact` quickly starts being unusable for large tasks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a type error in the function `readArray :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]` , it should have the type `readArray :: [Int] -> String` if you want that this expression works:

```
(showResults . maxSeqLength . readArray . readNQ)
```